# How to compare current user id with the id from one collection in firebase using React

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I´m trying to compare my current uid with uid from one collection, but im failing could someone please help me?

This is my Code:

```
    const user1 = auth.currentUser.uid;


const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const usersRef = collection(db, "Admin");
    const q = query(usersRef);
    const unsub = onSnapshot(q, querySnapshot => {
        let users = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            users.push(doc.data());
      });
      setUsers(users);
    });
    return () => unsub();
})

  console.log(users);


if(user1 === users.uid){}
```

Comment: Isn't `users` an array? In which case try `if (users.includes(user1)){}`

Answer (score 1):

In your case here, `users` is an array so you can't write:

```
if(user1 === users.uid){}
```

Instead you need to to find if `user1` exists in the `users` array first and then do the check like this:

```
const user1Found = users.find(user => user1 === user.uid);
if (user1Found) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is showing a list of many `users`. But a list does not have an `id` attribute.

The code is trying to compare a list of users to a single user.

Thus, `users.uid` will not work.

Only a single `user` object might have an `id`.

Query for a **single** user and compare its `id` along these lines: `user1 === user.uid`.